# put your own series in highcharts sereis

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I am trying to pass in my_series to series in highcharts to graph stacked bars. From my php, I get hash, which is like this:

{"Oat":{"10":"AA","11":"H"},"Brown Rice":{"10":"AA","11":"BB"}}

I actually dont know what is wrong with my code. I think it should work, but when I run it, I do not see anything on the screen. I checked that sample_name has "Oat" and "Brown Rice", which is what I want.

What I eventually want is a color-coded stacked bar graph that has samples on the yAxis and position on the xAxis. I think I almost got to what I want, it's just a problem with making an actual graph.

Thank you!

```
$(function() {

var allele_str = [];
var sample_name = [];
var hash = {};
var my_series = {
    data: []
};
var position = [];
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        inverted: true
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Gene'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [],
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Position'
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    }
    series: []
};

$.getJSON('6K_load.php', function(data) {
    sample_name = Object.keys(data);
    options.xAxis.categories.push(sample_name);
    for (var x in sample_name) { // sample Oat, BR
        for (var k in data[sample_name[x]]) { // pos
            series.name = k;
            var z = data[sample_name[x]][k];
            hash[z] = 1;
            allele_str.y = hash[z]; 
            if (z === 'AA') {
                allele_str.color = 'grey';
            }
            if (z === 'BB') {
                allele_str.color = 'blue';
            }
            if (z === '--') {
                allele_str.color = 'white';
            }
            if (z === 'H') {
                allele_str.color = 'red';
            }
            my_series.data.push(allele_str);
        }
        options.series.push(my_series);
    }
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
```

Comment: Have you appended your `chart` to the DOM? This might be an obvious question, but I just ask :-)

Comment: Yes, I did. I think there might be a problem with pushing data into series of highcharts.

Comment: can you post the data in my_series here. that may help us

Comment: What I want from my_series is to have 1's for y value and color names for color. So for example, if my z is "H", I want allele_str.y = 1 and allele_str.color = 'red' so that when I make bar chart, it's bar color is red. Basically I am using stacked bar code of highcharts but manipulate it a little bit so that bars with the same series.name can have different colors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you not parse your data to number value, you need to use parseFloat() in this line

```
my_series.data.push(parseFloat(allele_str));
```